# Log in on Stack Exchange and view questions from the only sites you are active on

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

I don't know if it's already possible, but it would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible using tag sets; a tag set can be "all questions from sites {x}, {y}, and {z}"

https://stackexchange.com/tagsets